# Number of group homomorphisms from infinite cyclic group to dihedral?

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups, group-homomorphism, dihedral-groups

Want to determine the number of group homomorphisms $f: \mathbb{Z} \to D_7$. My guess is that there is only $1$ because $0$ is the only element with finite order in $\mathbb{Z}$. Note a cyclic group is completely determined by its action on its generator, $1$ for $\mathbb{Z}$.

Is that reasoning correct?

Comment: Group homomorphism do not have to preserve order of elements. A homomorphism can map 1 to any group element, hence there are exactly as many homomorphisms as there are elements of $D_9.$

Comment: That is why $Z$ is called a free group on one generator.